# Javascript: convert JSON object to multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have an JSON object (hope so?):

```
[{"label":"label1","value":"value1"}
{"label":"label2","value":"value2"}
{"label":"label3","value":"value3"}]
```

I want to convert/extract that in 2 arrays like:

```
var labels = [label1,label2,label3]
var values = [value1,value2,value3]
```

I have no idea...

Comment: why do you want to create two arrays ? What is your goal exactly ?

Comment: What do you have? The thing you posted is not a valid json.

Comment: All options kills always my angularjs controller?!

Comment: I tried to use Angular Charts, as data input i need multiple Arrays, but i get from my mysql database a json object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to create your results:

```
var dataObj = [{"label":"label1","value":"value1"},
           {"label":"label2","value":"value2"},
           {"label":"label3","value":"value3"}];

var labels = dataObj.map(function(obj) {return obj.label;});
var values = dataObj.map(function(obj) {return obj.value;});
```

I think this solution is more elegant then manually iterating the array.

Comment: `var labels = dataObj.map(function(obj) {return obj.label;});` kills my angular controller, dont work

Comment: Got it working while putting the map function into the service-controller, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you would like two arrays and there is only ever two properties called label and value in each object, then this would be fine: -

```
var json_string = '[{"label":"label1", "value":"value1"}, {"label":"label2", "value":"value2"}, {"label":"label3", "value":"value3"}]';

var array = JSON.parse(json_string);

var labels = [];
var values = [];

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    labels.push(array[i].label);
    values.push(array[i].value);
}
```

Output: -

```
console.log(labels); // ["label1", "label2", "label3"]
console.log(values); // ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
```

Comment: `var array = JSON.parse(json_string);` kills my angular controller, dont work

Comment: Is the JSON you have a string? In your example it does not look like this, but suggested edit turned it into a string (as this does make sense). If it is not a string then simply ignore the quoted line and instead assign the data to var array directly (i.e. remove JSON.parse)

Answer (score 0):

One other implementation could be;

```
var dataObj = [{"label":"label1","value":"value1"},
               {"label":"label2","value":"value2"},
               {"label":"label3","value":"value3"}],
    dataStr = JSON.stringify(dataObj),
          r = /label":"(\w+).+?value":"(\w+)/g,
          m = [],
     values = [],
     labels = [];
while ((m = r.exec(dataStr)) !== null){
    labels.push(m[1]);
    values.push(m[2]);
}
console.log(labels, values); // [ 'label1', 'label2', 'label3' ] [ 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' ]
```

Comment: `dataStr = JSON.stringify(dataObj)` kills my angular controller, dont work

Answer (score 0):

A proposal with one object as result with dynamic keys.

```js
var array = [{ "label": "label1", "value": "value1" }, { "label": "label2", "value": "value2" }, { "label": "label3", "value": "value3" }],
    result = {};

array.forEach(function (a) {
    ['label', 'value'].forEach(function (k) {
        result[k] = result[k] || [];
        result[k].push(a[k]);
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: `array.forEach(function (a)` kills my angular controller, dont work